# React sticky canvas trying to hide it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, scroll

I'm trying to create an scrolling animation with a canvas. The problem I'm running in to is I want to change the "position" from sticky to something else so that it stays in the div.
Because right now that isn't the case as you can see down here.
[Image website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTObo.png)

If anyone has an idea please let me know

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import './index.css';

export default function animation(){
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const currentFrame = index => (
        `https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-     lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
    )
    const frameCount = 145;
    const canvasHeight = 770;
    const canvasWidth = 1158;
    const img  = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(1);
    const Canvas = props => {
        const canvasRef = useRef(null)
            useEffect(() => {
                const canvas = canvasRef.current
                const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
                img.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(img,0,0)
                }
                const updateImage = index =>{
                    img.src = currentFrame(index)
                    context.drawImage(img,0,0)  
                } 
                window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
                    const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
                    const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
                    const scrollFraction = scrollTop/maxScrollTop;
                    const frameIndex = Math.min(frameCount-1, Math.floor(scrollFraction * frameCount))
                    requestAnimationFrame(()=> updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
                })
    }, [])
        return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props}/>
    }

    return(
        <Canvas className="animation" width={canvasWidth} height={canvasHeight}></Canvas>
    )
}
```

```css
html{
  height: 100vh;
}
body{
  height: 400vh;
}
canvas{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 770px;
  max-width: 1158px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set div element position relative.

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't do the trick.